# Unity Oracle connection DllNotFoundException: oci

Tags: oracle, unity-container, oracle-call-interface, dllnotfoundexception

So basically I was trying to access an Oracle database within unity and mono-develop. I copied the needed DLLs System.Data and System.Data.OracleClient
from under: C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0 
to the Project's Assets folder,

Here's my C# code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OracleClient;


public class OracleConn : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string connectStr = "SomeConnectionString";
    string TBName = "CZRK";
    List<string> listOfID = new List<string>();                       //ID
    List<string> listOfName = new List<string>();                     //NAME

    private string content;


    void Start()
    {
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectStr);

        conn.Open(); //the line that causes error

    }

}
```

then the error DllNotFoundException: oci pops out when executing conn.Open()

the full error log:

```
DllNotFoundException: oci
System.Data.OracleClient.Oci.OciCalls.OCIEnvCreate (System.IntPtr& envhpp, OciEnvironmentMode mode, IntPtr ctxp, IntPtr malocfp, IntPtr ralocfp, IntPtr mfreep, Int32 xtramem_sz, IntPtr usrmempp)
System.Data.OracleClient.Oci.OciEnvironmentHandle..ctor (OciEnvironmentMode mode)
System.Data.OracleClient.Oci.OciGlue.CreateConnection (OracleConnectionInfo conInfo)
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionPoolManager.CreateConnection (OracleConnectionInfo info)
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionPool.CreateConnection ()
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionPool.GetConnection ()
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open ()
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection:Open ()
OracleConn.Start () (at Assets/OracleConn.cs:25)
```

Besides, I also tried copy the DLL file oci.dll from oracleDB_11g into the assets folder, but problem remains, any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error on 5.5.0f3 also trying to hit 11g. My suspicion is the current set of drivers go up to 10g. Therefore I went 3rd party. I got https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/ working quickly. Note, I DO NOT work for them.